# Leverage Java stream API to retrieve data from objects holding streamable collections themselves

Tags: java, java-stream

#### Problem statement

In my architecture there are data objects which I intend to display in a structured fashion. These objects look like this:

```
public class A
{
   private final String a1;

   public A( String a1 )
   {
      this.a1 = a1;
   }

   public String getA1()
   {
      return a1;
   }
}
```

```
public class B
{
   private final String b1;
   private final List<A> bList;

   public B( String b1, List<A> list )
   {
      this.b1 = b1;
      this.bList = list;
   }

   public String getB1()
   {
      return b1;
   }

   public List<A> getBList()
   {
      return bList;
   }
}
```

```
public class C
{
   private final String c1;
   private final int c2;
   private final List<B> cList;

   public C( String c1, int c2, List<B> list )
   {
      this.c1 = c1;
      this.c2 = c2;
      this.cList = list;
   }

   public String getC1()
   {
      return c1;
   }

   public int getC2()
   {
      return c2;
   }

   public List<B> getCList()
   {
      return cList;
   }
}
```

So an object `C` holds some values, as well as a list of objects `B` and those objects `B` hold some values of their own as well as respectively a list of objects `A`, which in turn hold some values themselves.

The requirements I am trying to comply with are **putting these into a JSON structure** and also **create a list of objects, where every entry looks like a collection of all of those data properties in a single object**. The latter is supposed to look like this:

```
public class D
{
   public final String a1;
   public final String b1;
   public final String c1;
   public final int c2;

   public D( String a1, String b1, String c1, int c2 )
   {
      this.a1 = a1;
      this.b1 = b1;
      this.c1 = c1;
      this.c2 = c2;
   }
}
```

The declared goal is to have those collected in a `List<D>`.

#### My solutions so far

The JSON structuring was easy to accomplish with Jackson:

```
C c = someGetterForC();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable( SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT );
try
{
   return mapper.writeValueAsString( c );
}
catch( JsonProcessingException e )
{
   // do error handling here
}
```

This gives me a well formatted JSON string and complies with the first requirement. For the second requirement I initially used a very trivial approach, *i.e.*  simply to collect all data in `for`-loops, thereby creating instances of `D` and putting them in a list. This looked somewhat like this:

```
List<D> dList = new ArrayList<>();
C c = someGetterForC();
for( B b : c.getCList() )
{
   for( A a : b.getBList() )
   {
      D d = new D( a.getA1(), b.getB1(), c.getC1(), c.getC2() )
      dList.add( d );
   }
}
```

However I would like to learn to do this using Java-Streams in order to create instances of `D`, because I am still having trouble with understanding some of its concepts. The struggle I am facing is with

- Streaming the list of objects `A` after streaming lists of object `B`
- Accessing non-list members from `A`, `B` and `C` in the same call and collecting them in instances of `D`

**Can this be done in a single stream-API call, *i.e.***

```
C c = someGetterForC();
c.stream()
// how to continue?
```

**and if so, does it make sense to do so?**

#### Notes

- Java 11 is mandatory, the project has currently no access to newer Java data structures
- The fact that given the `for`-loops there will be redundant data in the instances of `D` is of no concern and intended

#### Example

Assume there is an object `C c_alpha` which holds:

```
c1 = "car"
c2 = 42;
cList = {b_alpha, b_beta}
```

Where `B b_alpha` holds:

```
b1 = "boulder"
bList = {a_alpha}
```

And `B b_beta` holds:

```
b1 = "bomb"
bList = {a_beta, a_gamma}
```

Lastly there are the type `A` objects left, `A a_alpha` holds:

```
a1 = "ape"
```

`A a_beta` holds:

```
a1 = "andromeda"
```

And `A a_gamma` holds:

```
a1 = "axe"
```

Then the collected list of objects `D` that I am trying to get by leveraging the stream-API should look like this:

```
{ "42", "car", "boulder", "ape" },
{ "42", "car", "bomb", "andromeda" },
{ "42", "car", "bomb", "axe" },
```

#### TL;DR

Given objects which hold primitive types + strings as members, as well as lists of objects, which in turn hold primitive types + strings as members as well as lists of objects - how to stream them in a single call to retrieve tuples of the primitive types + strings accross all types in a single call?

I realize this is hard to properly formulate, the example above should clear things up.

Comment: are you sure you want to map everything on your own and not use something more flexible like [ModelMapper](https://modelmapper.org/)? The task looks predestined for a mapping lib.

Comment: @cyberbrain How to use that mapper to achieve my task? The mapping is not from `C` to `D`, but from `C` to a collection of objects `D`, where these are different permutations of `C` and collections held by `C` and more collections down the object hierarchy. After looking at the documentation I don't see yet how to achieve that, without defining custom property mappings that are probably more complex than just using `stream` for this specific use case. Can you apply "ModelMapper" to my trivial example (the real classes are even more convoluted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the same result as with your classical for-loop approach you need to use `flatMap`. Get the list of `B` s from your object and stream over it, flatmap and get every `A` for each `B` by calling `getBList()` and map the data to a new `D` object and finally collect to list of `D` objects. Something like below should give you what you are looking for

```
C c = someGetterForC();

List<D> dList = c.getCList()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMap(b -> b.getBList()
                                .stream()
                                .map(a -> new D(a.getA1(), b.getB1(), c.getC1(), c.getC2())))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am looking for. Going to apply this to my actual model and accept answer if the approach is suitable. Thank you!